# Can presented papers at conferences be listed in the reference section of Research Statements?

Tags: conference, presentation, research-statement

I have some presentation in conferences, which have not published as a proceeding or in a journal. I would like to know whether it is customary to put presented papers in the reference section and cite them in research statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references for a research statement follow the same customs as references in other academic documents.  So yes, you can cite conferences.

[Is it common to cite conference papers in a PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41593/is-it-common-to-cite-conference-papers-in-a-phd)